# VC++ Compiler options

Tags: visual-c++

I have a VC++ 6.0 project which I am now compiling using VS2008 . I have this piece of code that used to compile under VC++ 6  but throws an error under VS2008 :

```
int CIDStorage::Length()

{

CIDStorage* m_ptr = this;

    for(int i = 0;m_ptr->m_ptrNext != NULL;i++)
        m_ptr = m_ptr->m_ptrNext;

    if(i == 0)
        if(m_ID.IsEmpty())
            return 0;

    return i+1;
}
```

the error is    `'i' : undeclared identifier`

No probs with that I can see how that came about . So ... Do I change the source code . Or is there a compiler setting I could set that cures this ?

Comment: This is no longer compliant code.  You have to pull the declaration of i into the function and outside of the for loop.  The scoping rules were fixed since VC6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VC++ 6 (normally<sup>1</sup>) follows a pre-standard rule where a variable defined in a for loop remains defined for the rest of the scope in which that for loop resides. VC++ 2008 follows the standard rule where the for loop defines a new scope, and the variable is defined only within that scope.

The cure is pretty simple -- define the variable outside the loop:

```
int CIDStorage::Length()
{
    CIDStorage* m_ptr = this;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; m_ptr->m_ptrNext != NULL; i++)
        m_ptr = m_ptr->m_ptrNext;

    if(i == 0)
        if(m_ID.IsEmpty())
            return 0;

    return i+1;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The *compiler* in VC++ is actually capable of following the correct rules for scoping of variables defined in a `for` loop. Unfortunately, to follow the rule, you have to use the `/Za` flag, which tries to enforce *all* the rules it knows as strictly as possible. That turns out to be completely unusable because with that turned on, it rejects (virtually?) all of its own headers as containing errors!

Comment: Since it really doesn't work except maybe for very targeted demos, I've often wondered about whether `/Za` was just something MSVC has so it can pass some bureaucracy's requirement for 'standards compliance`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I *suspect* it's mostly a matter of poor coordination between the compiler people and the library people.